# Sorting XML on the Basis of Numeric Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Can anyone show me how to sort an XML file containing numeric data as well as string data stored in separate tags? For example I have a Charges (numeric) and Network (string) elements. Now I want to sort the XML file on the basis of Charges in Javascript.

any simple examples?

```
 <Results>
        <network>Wateen</network>
        <speed>2048</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
         <install_charges>500</install_charges>
         <charges>20</charges>
    </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>2000</charges>
   </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>200</charges>
   </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>3000</charges>
   </Results>
```

How do I sort the above XML according to the `charges`? It will also be nice if it is non-XSL method because XSL give lots of trouble.

Comment: Could you post an example xml string?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use XSL you can make an array containing the Results-elements and use the native sort-method of arrays:

```
<Results>
        <network>Wateen</network>
        <speed>2048</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
         <install_charges>500</install_charges>
         <charges>20</charges>
    </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>2000</charges>
   </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>200</charges>
   </Results>

   <Results>
        <network>PTCL</network>
        <speed>4096</speed>
        <type>Fixed</type>
       <install_charges>0</install_charges>
       <charges>3000</charges>
   </Results>
<script>

var nodeArray=[];
var nodeList=document.getElementsByTagName('Results')

//fill array
for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;++i)
{
  nodeArray.push(nodeList[i]);
}

//sort array
nodeArray.sort(function(a,b)
              {
                return (
                         Number(a.getElementsByTagName('charges')[0].firstChild.data)
                          -
                         Number(b.getElementsByTagName('charges')[0].firstChild.data)
                        );
              });

//reorder nodes
for(var i=nodeArray.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
  nodeArray[i]
   .parentNode
     .insertBefore(nodeArray[i],
                   nodeArray[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('Results')[0]);
}
</script>
```